# Es6 generators cartesian

Tags: javascript

I have function to calculate cartesian combinations:

```
function cartes1(a, b, c) {
    let arr = []
    for (let i1 of a) {
        for (let i2 of b) {
            for (let i3 of c) {
                arr.push([i1, i2, i3])
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

I want to convert it to generator to be stopped when needed, so did this:

```
function* cartes(a, b, c) {
    for (let i1 of a) {
        for (let i2 of b) {
            for (let i3 of c) {
                yield [i1, i2, i3]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code is basically the same but the second returns wrong results.

```
cartes1([1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]) // correct
cartes([1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3])
```

The generator returns this:

```
[[ 1, 1, 1 ]
[ 1, 1, 2 ]
[ 1, 1, 3 ]]
```

The generator function is called with

```
cartes(range(1)(3)(1), range(1)(3)(1), range(1)(3)(1))
const range = from => to => function*(step=1) {
    for(let i=from;i<=to;i+=step) {
        yield i
    }
}
```

Am I missing something ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you did is to use three generators, but if they are finished, you can not rewind them.

To prevent this, you could return jzs the closure over the collected value and call the genrator at the first time in the `for` loop.

[`Generator#next`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/next) returns `done` if the gerator has reached the the final `return`, either directly by using this statement or at the end of the function.

[`function*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) states:

> The `next()` method returns an object with a `value` property containing the yielded value and a `done` property which indicates whether the generator has yielded its last value as a boolean. Calling the `next()` method with an argument will resume the generator function execution, replacing the yield expression where execution was paused with the argument from `next()`.
>
> A `return` statement in a generator, when executed, will make the generator finished (i.e the `done` property of the object returned by it will be set to true). If a value is returned, it will be set as the `value` property of the object returned by the generator.
>
> Much like a `return` statement, an error thrown inside the generator will make the generator finished -- unless caught within the generator's body.
>
> **When a generator is finished, subsequent `next` calls will not execute any  of that generator's code, they will just return an object of this form: `{value: undefined, done: true}`.** [emph by ns]

```js
function* cartes(a, b, c) {
    for (let i1 of a()) {
        for (let i2 of b()) {
            for (let i3 of c()) {
                yield [i1, i2, i3];
            }
        }
    }
}

const range = from => to => (step = 1) => function* () {
    for (let i = from; i <= to; i += step) {
        yield i;
    }
};

for (let v of cartes(range(1)(3)(1), range(1)(3)(1), range(1)(3)(1))) {
    console.log(v);
}
```

Comment: This converts them to array. I dont want that. I want to be generator. I am already using for of, but why it stops after the first iterations of the first array

Comment: Thanks, but why the generator is finished. for (let if1 of a) - why only the first combination is returned, doesnt it make sense to go through all of the elements of the first element

Comment: `i1` isn't finished, but the last `i3`. that prevent getting values for `i2`, because by running the most inner for loop, you get no value anymore. generators store their position and if finished ... it stops.